# Hide/Show form in HTML produce unusual result

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've been trying for some time now (some time = whole day) to figure out why I have this strange problem with my form. I have a client who wants a stand-alone HTML page running locally which would display one form with couple of textbox and one button. After info is entered and user click that button, a second form should show up with new textboxes. Form can't have a redirection to another website or file. It all has to be in that (HTML) file.

I figured out this would be easiest to do with jQuery but loading whole library just to hide one form is plain stupid. So I take a look at other option and decided to use pure Javascript.

The problem is when I click "NEXT" first time the 1st form disappear but then apear a second later like some sort of request is sent. Bellow is the code I currently have. I tried making an JSFiddle but browser blocks every time I access it.

**Javascript**:

```
function hideAll() {
  document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
  showFirstForm();
}

function showFirstForm() {
  if (document.getElementById('second').style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function showSecondForm() {
  if (document.getElementById('first').style.display == 'block')
  {
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body class="if5" onload="hideAll()"> // I'm loading hideAll() on refresh to hide second form
   ....
    <!-- FORM 2 -->
    <form id="first" action="#" class='tx_anmelden' method="post" autocomplete="off" >

    <filedset>
    <label for="name"> Your name </label>
    <input name="name" value="MyName" /></input>
    <button onClick="showFirstForm()">Next</button>
    </filedset>
    </form>


    <!-- FORM 1 -->
    <form id="second" class='tx_anmelden'>

    <fieldset>
    <label for="name"> Your name </label>
    <input name="name" value="MyNaffffffme" /></input>
    <button onClick="showSecondForm()">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
   ....
```

*References*:

- [getElementByID](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: You are saying to show the second form in the second form and show the first form in the first. See the problem?

Comment: @epascarello is correct, you have the comment correct, but the id in the form switched.  You have a few other problems too, I put a working jsfiddle link down in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that you have your form id's switched, `<button>` has a default type of `submit`.  So when your button is clicked it is posting the form to `#`.  So correct your form ids, and then change your button code type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" onClick="showSecondForm()">Next</button>
```

Here are some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Here is a working jsfiddle using the corrected code: http://jsfiddle.net/789SP/

Comment: That did the trick. The submit button was sending request and page was loading automatically again. I repaired the "bug". Thanks for JSFiddle contribution, my code is similar. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

First off, any button in a form that doesn't have a type attribute or has a type attribute of submit will by default submit the form on click.

Second, it looks like you are trying to implement some sort of wizard. If this is true you don't want each part to be it's own form because at the end you're going to want to send all of this data to the server which won't work if it's in two forms.

The entire thing needs to be in one form with sections inside that you show/hide. To navigate between the sections you'll want to use

`<button type="button" onClick="showSecondForm()">Next</button>`

To do wizards is always a pain in the butt. Once you start handling validation you need to figure out which step has an error in it and show that section, or if the user uses the back button they might expect the form to go back to step one. You might want to search for a third party solution that provides some of the boiler plate functionality. [These might help](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/wizard/)

This should get you off to a good start though.

**Edit**

Don't attempt this from scratch. Use [this](http://www.jquery-steps.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- FORM 2 -->
<form id="first" action="#" class='tx_anmelden' method="post" autocomplete="off" >

<fieldset> **fieldset was misspelled as "filedset"**
<label for="name"> Your name </label>
<input name="name" value="MyName"></input> **your input had /> at it's end, which is unfortunately wrong**
<button onClick="showFirstForm()">Next</button>
</fieldset> **fieldset was misspelled as "filedset"**
</form>


<!-- FORM 1 -->
<form id="second" class='tx_anmelden'>

<fieldset>
<label for="name"> Your name </label>
<input name="name" value="MyNaffffffme"></input> **your input again had /> at it's end, which is unfortunately wrong**
<button onClick="showSecondForm()">Next</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```